# Simplify Fraction with a Square Root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to simplify a problem that I have the answer to but when I check it with Wolfram it seems a bit more simplified and I can't think of what steps are taking place to get that result.

Somehow this: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}}$

Becomes this: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$

And I'm not sure how. I'm guessing its some simple Algebra operation that I'm totally forgetting right now. Any help breaking it down is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $2=\sqrt{4}$. Therefore
$$2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}} = \sqrt{4}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}} = \sqrt{4\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}=\sqrt{4-x^2}.$$

Comment: I think this one helped. So is it safe for me to assume that the process would be: combine 1 and x^2/4 to become 4x^2/4, then when you bring sqrt(4) in the 4's in 4x^2/4 cancel and you end up with 4-x^2?

Answer (score 0):

$a\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a^2b}$.

This moves the 2 inside the $\sqrt{}$ where it becomes $2^2 = 4$.

Comment: Sorry I said I should have said I understood that the 4 is from the 2. I just couldn't figure out how the 4 in x^2/4 cancels.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(4-x^2)}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}.$$